# Export/Embed Interactive Python Plotly Visualisation with Dropdown Menu

Tags: python, html, export, plotly, interactive

I have been trying to export an interactive correlation heatmap, created in juypter notebook with plotly, to html etc. for embedding it into a webpage/dashboard.

I realise that the dropdown/scroll bar decision in the graph refers to data which is not (automatically) exported with plotly.

Could you give me a hit on how to make an interactive visualisation, such as the example below, exportable for html or similar.

Thanks a lot,
Fabian

```
# Load packages
import pandas as pd
import random

# Define DF
item1 = random.sample(range(20), 20)
item2 = random.sample(range(20), 20)
item3 = random.sample(range(20), 20)
item4 = random.sample(range(20), 20)
revenue = random.sample(range(20), 20)

df = pd.DataFrame({'item1': item1,
                    'item2': item2,
                    'item3': item3,
                    'item4': item4,
                    'revenue': revenue})
```

Then

```
# Create Interactive Correlation Heatmap
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

from ipywidgets import interact

names = ['item1','item2','item3','item4']
x = names
y = names


def plot_it(level):

    z = df[['item1','item2','item3','item4']][(df['revenue']<=level)].corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
    z = z.round(2).values.tolist()

    annotations = []
    for n, row in enumerate(z):
        for m, val in enumerate(row):
            var = z[n][m]
            annotations.append(
                dict(
                    text=str(val),
                    x=x[m], y=y[n],
                    xref='x1', yref='y1',
                    font=dict(color='white' if val > 0.3 else 'black'),
                    showarrow=False)
                )

    colorscale = [[0, '#32cbdb'], [1, '#228a95']]  # custom colorscale
    trace = Heatmap(x=x, y=y, z=z, colorscale=colorscale, showscale=False)

    heatmap = Figure(data=[trace])
    heatmap['layout'].update(
        title="Correlation Heatmap <br> Revenue < {}".format(level),
        annotations=annotations,
        xaxis=dict(ticks='', side='top', tickangle=-15, domain=[0.05, 0.95]),
        # ticksuffix is a workaround to add a bit of padding
        yaxis=dict(ticks='', ticksuffix='  ', tickangle=-50, domain=[0.05, 0.95]),
        width=800,
        height=800,
        autosize=False
    )
    iplot(heatmap)

interact(plot_it, level=(10,20,10))
```